# Pass property for single project on commandline when building a solution

Tags: msbuild

When I use msbuild to build a solution containing multiple projects, can I pass a property on the command line in a way that the property will only be used for one of the projects?

That means, can I say that `-p:Foo=42` shall be used for Project1, but not for Project2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MSBuild** cannot specify a property for one of the project by the solution file(`msbuild xxx\xxx.sln`) easily and [only targets can be specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019). Or you have to type multiple msbuild command line to specify to the related csproj file to enable that changed property like `msbuild Project1.csproj -t:build -p:xxx=xxx`, `msbuild Project2.csproj -t:build`. However, it is too complex and inconvenient.

**So** I recommend that you could use msbuild script to get what you want.

**1)** create a file called `build.proj` file:

```
<Project>        
    
  <ItemGroup>
              
     <!--add all the projects from the solution and remove the any project you want to modify the foo property-->
     <MostProjectFile Include="**\*.csproj;**\*.vcxproj" Exclude="**\Project1.csproj" />
              
     <!--add any projects you want to modify the foo value-->
     <SpecialProjectFile Include="**\Project1.csproj" />
              
  </ItemGroup>
            
            
  <Target Name="Build">
            
  <!--build the most projects and remove the project which you want to change foo property-->
  <MSBuild Projects="@(MostProjectFile)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Debug"/>
            
  <!--build any projects that wants to modify the foo property separately-->
  <MSBuild Projects="@(SpecialProjectFile)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Foo=42"/>
            
  </Target>
            
</Project>
```

**2)** if you want to change the foo property again, you can just modify the `build.proj` based on your needs.

Run `msbuild xxx\build.proj -t:Build` to build it.